# How to use datepicker in your form using jqueryui?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

I need some help to use my checkbox, where a user will use checkbox in order for the datepicker or calendar be displayed immediately when checkbox is used to lock- up until. Need some help on the jquery side in order my logic be functional. When a user unchecked after locking using calendor or datepicker, this must be hidden. I am also getting datepicker is not a function....?

```
<div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Lockuntil, new { @class = "rb", id = "Lockuntil" })

            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateSelect, new { @class = "datepicker", id = "TextValue" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Jquery for datechecking-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#Lockuntil').on('click', onClickCheckBox); // bind an event with checkbox on click. On click function onClickCheckBox will be called.

                onClickCheckBox(); // to hide or show on page load.c
            });

            function onClickCheckBox() // logic to show hide textbox based on checkbox's value.
            {
                if ($('#Lockuntil').is(":checked")) {
                    $("#TextValue").show();
                }
                else {
                    $("#TextValue").hide();
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: did you add required cdn for using [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) ?

Comment: @Swati had a work around, now the issue my datepicker is not showing and need some help to this updated logic posted.

Comment: Note that you can use `$("#datepicker").toggle($(this).is(":checked"))` to reduce the amount of code in `onClickCheckBox`. Note that you are attaching the event listener both in jQuery (with `on('click'`) and in HTML (with `onclick="`), which could be causing problems.

Comment: @Heretic the check and unchecking is working after i redo this logic to this one being updated to the forum. But issue now Texbox is not displaying datepicker and need some help on this.

Comment: You didn't initialize datepicker in your updated code ? i.e :`$('#TextValue').datepicker({..`

Comment: Sounds like you have a different question then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.form-group').on('click', '.rb', function(e) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("#TextValue").datepicker("enable");
    } else {
      $("#TextValue").datepicker("disable");
    }
  });
  $("#TextValue").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="rb" id="Lockuntil" checked />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="TextValue" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You must include all the proper libraries. You must then initialize the UI Widgets you wish to use.

See More: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/